# QPushButton background-color overlaps border

Tags: c++, css, qt, background-color, qpushbutton

I am using `QPushButton` class and adding the object to a `QGraphicsProxyWidget` after setting the style sheet.  However, when I set a `border-radius`, the `background-color` still overlaps the border. How do I get rid of this?

**Example:** (where levelOneEasyProxy is `QGrpahicsProxyWidget`)

```
QPushButton* levelOneEasyButton = new QPushButton();
levelOneEasyButton->setGeometry(QRect(sceneRect().width()*0.05, sceneRect().height()*0.2, 70, 50));
levelOneEasyButton->setText("1");
levelOneEasyButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {"
                                  "background-color: rgb(92, 249, 158);"
                                  "color: white;"
                                  "font-size: 16px;"
                                  "border-style: solid;"
                                  "border-width: 2px;"
                                  "border-radius: 10px;"
                                  "}"
                                  "QPushButton:pressed {"
                                  "background-color: rgb(66, 191, 118);"
                                  "}");
levelOneEasyProxy = addWidget(levelOneEasyButton);
levelOneEasyProxy->setZValue(10.0);
```

**Current Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that using the code above will set the `border-radius` but the background needs to be set to `translucent` by using `setAttribute` on the `QPushButton`.  This can be done with the following code:

```
qPushButtonObject->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

This will get rid of the overlapping `background-color`.